# PHP json_encode error: Empty last record

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to read a file with ajax, but I get an arror

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: **unexpected non-whitespace character** after JSON data at line 1 column 48 of the JSON data

Because upon inspection, I always end up with `""` as the last record...?!

Here is the `test.txt` file:

```
one
two
three
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'control.php',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: details,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            $("#whitelist").append(data[0])
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, responseText) {
            // alert('complete')
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
            // var responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

And here is `control.php`, that reads the file and supposedly sends a json-encoded array back:

```
  $path = "test.txt";
  $file = fopen($path, 'r');
  $data = fread($file, filesize($path));
  fclose($file);

  $lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,$data);

  error_log('Lines: ' . json_encode($lines, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) . "err: " . json_last_error());
  error_log('Lines: ' . serialize($lines));
  echo json_encode($lines, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Here is the `error_log()` output:

```
Lines: {"0":"one","1":"two","2":"three","3":""} json_last_error: 0
```

And here is the firebug output:

```
{"0":"one","1":"two","2":"three","3":""}{"error":"Error","message":[]}
```

It's been hours now!! Where in hell does this `""` come from? Also, why is `json_last_error()` not helping at all? Why is it so hard to build a simple json array?

I'm obviously doing something very wrong. Please show me to the light, I'm exhausted.

Comment: Have you checked if your last row in your testfile `test.txt` ends with a carriage return / line feed? If so, this would produce an empty item in your `$lines` array.

Comment: @xaccrocheur can you add test.txt file contents

Comment: @Bjoern yes I did, in vi the cursor is on the `t` of "three" and the line below is an empty `~` one. Is there another way to check if there is indeed an empty line in my file?

Comment: When you invoke the script form a browser (directly, not via ajax) what's in the _source code view_? Maybe some php error/warning message?

Comment: @VolkerK your comment lead me to the solution: There was a rogue `echo` somewhere in the file that probably messed up the json array. Also, your answer works for me, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're reading the whole contents of the file into memory anyway, there's an easier way to get it split by line feed/breaks *and* ignore empty lines

```
$data = file($path,  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
echo json_encode($lines, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

see http://docs.php.net/function.file

Comment: OK, it works, just remove the second line, as $data is a well-formed array at that stage :) Thanks again, guys.

Comment: the `$data=file(...)` line would replace almost all of the other stuff you've posted, from `$file = fopen...` on.

Answer (score 1):

could you please try the below code in control.php after error.log

```html
$lines = array_slice($lines, 0, count($lines)-1);
echo json_encode($lines, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Hope it will help you to sort out problem

Comment: Thak you very much for your help @sagar ; I tried that, I tried array_filter(), they all do the job of removing this empty last record (I feel dirty) but no matter what *json_encode keeps inserting* this `{"error":"Error","message":[]}` what did I do to the stars?!

Answer (score 1):

in your control.php file just replace the line

```
$lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
```

with

```
$lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,trim($data));
```

I have tested it and its gives output as

```
{"0":"one","1":"two","2":"three"}
```

using trim() will remove any unwanted whitespace

Also if the file is empty , then fread() will produce a warning

```
fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0
```

to prevent this final code should be something like this

```
<?php
$path  = "test.txt";
$lines = '';

if(filesize($path)>0){
    $file  = fopen($path, 'r');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($path));
    $lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,trim($data));
    fclose($file);
}

echo json_encode($lines, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

only if file is not empty , then we have the need to open & read the file